# Rails ActiveCampaign gem - wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the ActiveCampaign gem in Rails to connect to the ActiveCampaign API: https://github.com/RushPlay/active_campaign

I am trying to perform a simple function: connect to the CRM and upload one contact. I've applied the following code:

```
ac = ActiveCampaign::Client.new('https://mywebsite.api-us1.com','mycode')
ac.contact_sync({ "email" => "test@test.com","first_name" => "John","last_name" => "Doe" })
```

Unfortunately rails spits back the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

active_campaign (0.1.9) lib/active_campaign/client.rb:15:in `initialize'
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/RushPlay/active_campaign/blob/master/lib/active_campaign/client.rb#L15-L20), `ActiveCampaign::Client#initialize` takes one argument which should be options hash. You try to pass it two arguments.

Comment: I tried changing the code to:
ac = ActiveCampaign::Client.new({:api_method => 'https://website.api-us1.com',:api_key => 'mycode'})
Now it gives the error:
undefined method `query=' for #<HTTPI::Request:0x007fbb52ca51b0>
active_campaign (0.1.9) lib/active_campaign/client.rb:64:in `create_request'
active_campaign (0.1.9) lib/active_campaign/client.rb:51:in `request'
active_campaign (0.1.9) lib/active_campaign/client.rb:45:in `post'
active_campaign (0.1.9) lib/active_campaign/client/contacts.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Contacts>'
Any ideas?